# Android fade out when clicked ImageView that is overlay over applications

Tags: android, imageview

I want to create an ImageView in a service class and want to show this imageview overlay of all applications. also I want to fade out my image when user clicked on it. I try lots of code but i can't disapear the imageview smoothly.
This is my onCreate method of service that want to show imageview:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery_20);

    final Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(50);
    fadeOut.setDuration(2000);

    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            chatHead.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    });


    chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            chatHead.setAnimation(fadeOut);
            //fadeOut.start();
            chatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });


    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 30;
    params.y = 30;
    params.height=150;
    params.width=100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

}
```

what wrong i do?
tnx in advance!

Comment: `I try lots of code but i can't disapear the imageview smoothly.` This means you are able to disappear it? Or not?

Comment: @Sash_KP  no, i can disappear it but not animationaly!
I want to fade out my imageview but i can't :(

Answer (score 0):

For proper fading out of image i would suggest you to follow below steps.

First of all , create xml that defines the animation. This file should be located under `anim` folder under `res` directory `(res ⇒ anim ⇒ fade_out.xml)`. If you don’t have `anim` folder in your `res` directory create one.

```
fade_out.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

Then in your `activity`

```
Animation fadeOut;

// load the animation
fadeOut= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_out); 

    // button click event
    chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            // start the animation
            chatHead.startAnimation(animFadein);

            chatHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }
    });
```